# Appending Syntax Error to HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, yql

I'm using YQL and jQuery.ajax to retrieve an inline JavaScript variable from another website. This variable contains a complete XML document that base64 encoded.

While the AJAX request is working, I can't figure out how to take the `res.query.results` and append it to a dynamically made `<script>` element.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/dj/fsp?format=json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(res) {
      var sc = $('script');
      $(sc).append(document.createTextNode('var '+$(res.query.results)));
      $('head').append(sc);
    }
});
```

Here's what the console log is telling me:

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. To *create* a script element, you do `$('<script>')`, not `$('script')`. The latter *searches for* all `script` elements.
2. No need for `createTextNode`, jQuery will handle that for you.
3. You're over-doing it with the calls to `$()`:

   ```
         var sc = $('<script>');
         sc.append(document.createTextNode('var '+res.query.results));
     //  ^ #1 (see below)                         ^ #2
   ```

   1. You don't want to do `$(sc)` again, it's pointless, it's already a jQuery instance.
   2. You don't want to *parse* `res.query.results` into a jQuery instance, you want to grab the string into a JavaScript variable (apparently).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ronig/1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    display("Doing query...");
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/dj/fsp?format=json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(res) {
        display("Got result, creating <code>script</code>...");
        var sc = $('<script>');
        sc.append('var '+res.query.results);
        $('head').append(sc);
        display("length of <code>txt</code> global variable: " + window.txt.length);
      }
    });

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```